# Using Double Ended Queues (Deques) for Transposing sequences

Tags: algorithm, deque

This is an interesting question that might be more interesting than useful. Say I want to copy two deques(`DQ1_a` and `DQ1_b`) into their copies (`DQ2_a` and `DQ2_b`).

```
DQ1_a= <A,B,C,D,E,F>
DQ1_b= <G,H,I,J,K,L,M>
```

But we want to exchange the "strands" at `D<->J`. Thus we want to end up with

```
DQ2_a= <A,B,C,(D or J),K,L,M>
DQ2_b= <G,H,I,(J or D),E,F>
```

The `or` exists because it depends on whether include the elements marking the exchange is in it or not.

`Question 1`: Find an algorithm to end up with the transposed datastructure `DQ2_*` starting from the given deques `DQ1_*` and the exchanged elements `ex=(D<->J); ex[a]=D; ex[b]=J`. Allowed are the **deque operations** - `left_push,left_pop,right_push,right_pop,deque_empty`(last one returns whether the deque is empty or not).

Solution:

```
left_item  <- left_pop(DQ1_a)
while (left_item!=ex[a]):
  right_push(DQ2_a,left_item)
  left_item<-left_pop(DQ1_a)

right_item <- right_pop(DQ1_b)
while (right_item!=ex[b]):
  left_push(DQ2_b,right_item)
  right_item<-right_pop(DQ1_b)

# if not inclusive
right_push(DQ2_a,left_item)
left_push(DQ2_b,right_item)
# else 
#right_push(DQ2_b,left_item)
#left_push(DQ2_a,right_item)

left_item  <- left_pop(DQ1_b)
while (not deque_empty(DQ1_b)):
  right_push(DQ2_a,left_item)
  left_item<-left_pop(DQ1_a)

right_item <- right_pop(DQ1_a)
while (not deque_empty(DQ1_a)):
  left_push(DQ2_b,right_item)
  right_item<-rightt_pop(DQ1_a)
```

`Question 2`: This is what beats me. Given a set of `DQ1_*` (more than 2) - you have to copy them to `DQ2_*` using the list of exchanges

```
ex={s: s is a given set of exchanges of the form: (ith element of DQ1_x)<->(jth element of DQ1_y)}
```

Any better solutions to this problem are welcome!!